# Override radio button for fancytree

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I am writing my website using the FancyTree library and got stuck with this problem:

I am using skin-awesome as my theme, and add glyph(preset4) as an extension. However, I can't change the icon of the checkbox whatsoever. This means that even though tree.checkbox has been set to "radio", the checkbox icons stays the same.

Have been looking on the Internet for a while and couldn't get anything close. Any feedback would be great. Thanks

Comment: This is not yet implemented in v2.25 for ext-glyph. I recommend to open an issue for this

Comment: Nice job downvoting without explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I end up doing:

- I hooked into createNode callback, swapping the icon to the checkbox icon through accessing DOM from node.li
- Second part that I have to do is make sure that when the node is selected/deselected, the icon has to be changed properly. This is done by hooking into select callback, check node.isSelected, find the icon, and switching it on/off.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

This missing feature was added for Fancytree release 2.26.

See this issue for details:
[Radio button support for ext-glyph](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/791)

Comment: Might worth allowing nature input. The theme is nice but having he ability to use something native would be better

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a Radio buttons by providing font awesome icon for it.

Like This

[image]

the following are our html code to produce this behavior using Fancytree v2.24.0:

```
<link href="components/jquery.fancytree/dist/skin-bootstrap/ui.fancytree.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="components/jquery.fancytree/dist/jquery.fancytree-all.min.js"></script>
```

And this is our javascript code to generate this tree:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        (function ($) {
            glyph_opts = {
                map: {
                    doc: "fa fa-file-o",
                    docOpen: "fa fa-file",
                    checkbox: "fa fa-circle-o",
                    checkboxSelected: "fa fa-dot-circle-o",
                    checkboxUnknown: "fa fa-minus-square-o",
                    dragHelper: "fa fa-arrows",
                    dropMarker: "fa fa-arrow-right",
                    error: "fa fa-exclamation-triangle",
                    expanderClosed: "fa fa-chevron-right",
                    expanderLazy: "fa fa-chevron-right", // glyphicon-plus-sign
                    expanderOpen: "fa fa-chevron-down", // glyphicon-collapse-down
                    folder: "fa fa-folder",
                    folderOpen: "fa fa-folder-open",
                    loading: "fa fa-refresh fa-spin"
                }
            };

            $("#Checkboxes_Fancytree_id").fancytree({
                extensions: ["glyph"],
                checkbox: "radio",
                selectMode: 1,
                glyph: glyph_opts,
                // tooltip: true,
                // tooltip: function(event, data) { return data.node.title + "!"},
                source: [
                    {title: "n1 (checkbox: false)", expanded: true, checkbox: false, children: [
                            {title: "n1.1"},
                            {title: "n1.2 (selected)", selected: true},
                            {title: "n1.3"}
                        ]},
                    {title: "n2", expanded: true, checkbox: false, children: [
                            {title: "n2.1"},
                            {title: "n2.2"},
                            {title: "n2.3"}
                        ]}
                ]
            });
        }(jQuery));
    });
</script>
```

And this is an online demo for our development:

http://demo.javatmp.com/JavaTMP-Static-Ajax/#pages/plugins/tree/fancytree/radio_buttons_fancytree.html

I hope those information help you and if you have any suggestions for improving ours, so kindly tell me.

Comment: This is not the good walk around since this is just change of icon. I need something that work with both checkbox: true and false. This will be dynamically anf only known at request time.

Comment: Starting with v2.26, there will be native support for radio buttons: The preset map contains 'radio' and 'radioSelected' as well. (also, v2.27 will extend the syntax a bit, providing ligature font icon support)